# Convert json response to formatted table in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I have a category list that already been flattened but not sure how I can convert it to table that looks like below example. So if has children is equal to false then that will be my id and then if has children is true I'll get the name and so on. I think it can be done by looping the category list

```
"response": {
    "category_list": [
      {
        "category_id": 100017,
        "parent_category_id": 0,
        "name": "Women Clothes",
        "has_children": true
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100118,
        "parent_category_id": 100017,
        "name": "Socks & Stockings",
        "has_children": true
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100419,
        "parent_category_id": 100118,
        "name": "Others",
        "has_children": false
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100418,
        "parent_category_id": 100118,
        "name": "Pantyhose",
        "has_children": false
      },
      {
        "category_id": 100417,
        "parent_category_id": 100118,
        "name": "Socks",
        "has_children": false
      }
]
}
```

So result should be like this:

| Id | Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 | Category 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100419 | Women Clothes | Socks & Stockings | Others |  |
| 100417 | Women Clothes | Socks & Stockings | Pantyhose |  |
| 100418 | Women Clothes | Socks & Stockings | Socks |  |

Comment: Please do not remove info which answer are (probably) based on. Questions are supposed to remain answerable, even after having been answered. (You are right to remove anything which is an answer, if that is what you did please accept my apology. In that case however, please create your own answer with the answering parts which you removed from the question. If you remove them again and describe your edit accordingly, then that edit will be left.)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for -

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(d['category_list'])
```

Assuming d is a dictionary, and d['category_list'] is a list

Comment: Oh but i needed to convert that category list to looks like table shown

Comment: It came up like that only

Comment: my category list has a logic to follow not only converting to table

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using python pandas to create a data frame from JSON

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_json('data.json')
 print(df.to_string())
```